# connection closes unexpectedly with different kind of errors

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows

When I execute a query which returns more than 300 rows I’m getting random errors and the connection closes for example

```
  An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

Or

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 73
```

Or

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 196
```

And it only happens when I’m logged in in my computer (windows 7) with my profile, but when I’m logged in in a different computer with my profile or a another user in my computer it does work

Any Help??

Comment: Did you launch SSMS with admin privilege on your windows 7 machine ?

Comment: @kin Yes I did try.

Comment: @kin  I know I asked this question a long time ago but I still want to share what the problem was. It was that my computer was shut down unexpectedly due to a black out and the some files where corrupted (yes now I got an battery backup...) had to clean up registry etc,